How to create horizontal RangeBar chart series with x-axis as time similar to a Gantt style chart in C# with MSchart
I am trying to create a chart that looks like this:

Each bar represents an object over time with each color representing a state change. For example , when the segment is green i.e. L1 = good, light blue i.e. L2 = Very good, red i.e. L0 = bad, etc.
The segment color is sized based on the amount of time along the x-axis when the object was in that state.
Is it possible to create a chart of this style winforms C#? How?
A Code example will be appreciated!
Thanks for your help!
I tried looking for a solution online but couldn't find anything.
public TimeRangeBarChart() {  
InitializeComponent(); YAxis.LabelStyle.Enabled = true; YAxis.Minimum = 0; YAxis.Maximum = 2; }

Is there a way to do this?
